# Throwable and Exception in Java

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception, throwable, randoop

Suppose I have a class named BugException which extends from `RuntimeException`
And BugException has a copy constructor which takes a Throwable.

This code compiles and typechecks:

```
Throwable e = ...;
if (e instanceof BugException) {
   throw new BugException(e);
}
```

Why is it that:

```
Throwable e = ...;
if (e instanceof BugException) {
   throw e;
}
```

Does not compile and gives the error message: unhandled exception. java.lang.Throwable. ?

Why is this unnecessary wrapping necessary to satisfy the typechecker?

Comment: Testing `instanceof` doesn't change `e`'s static type.

Comment: Or you can simply cast, without the wrapper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At compile time, it is not know what kind of exception `e` is. It might be a checked Exception, in which case the compiler will need you to either wrap the `throw` in a try/catch or make the method throw it.

However, if you explicitly cast the unchecked exception, then it will compile.

```
Throwable e = ...;
if (e instanceof BugException) {
   throw (BugException) e;
}
```